# How to generate table from model in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ado.net

How is it possible to create an entity in the visual studio designer and generate a table from it? I find it much easier to generate my entities within VS than to create a table in SQL Server.

Also, if I do generate an entity from table, is it possible to make changes to the entity and push them to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF, at least in the current version, doesn't support this. There isn't a mechanism to create the database; likewise, when you resync, it updates the model *from* the database.

Perhaps use "data dude" (VS2008 Database Edition) to make your changes at the database?